# ForbiddenAttributesError with Grape and ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, grape-api

I have a ruby application using Grape, and it doesn't have rails.

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class API::Articles < Grape::API
  post '/articles' do
    article = Article.create(params[:article])
  end
end
```

`Article.create` gives `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError:`

There is some discussion about it
[here](https://github.com/intridea/grape/issues/404), but I don't
understand it. I've tried this suggestion:

```
post '/articles' do
  article = Article.create(permitted_params[:article])
  represent(article, env)
end

helpers do
  def permitted_params
    @permitted_params ||= declared(params, include_missing: false)
  end
end
```

This time `@permitted_params` is empty so attributes are gone.

I've also tried wrapping th hash with `ActionController::Parameters`, but that fails with other errors.

What is the suggested solution to solve `ForbiddenAttributesError`, in Grape as of now?

Grape uses hashie gem for `params`, and [their solution](https://github.com/intridea/hashie/blob/master/UPGRADING.md#compatibility-with-rails-4-strong-parameters) for this is to include a gem called hashie_rails, but this gem brings all the rails with it, but I don't want any of that. So I need a vanilla solution.

Comment: If you wouldn't like to use Hashie gem, just convert your @permitted_params to hash: `@permitted_params ||= declared(params, include_missing: false).to_hash`

Answer (score 0):

https://gist.github.com/smd686s/6320643

`Gemfile`

```
gem "actionpack", "~> 4.0.0"
```

`app.rb`

```
require 'rack/test'
require 'action_controller/metal/strong_parameters'

#https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/test/controller/parameters/parameters_require_test.rb

module Application
  class API < Grape::API

    helpers do
      def item_params
        ActionController::Parameters.new(params).require(:item).permit(:attribute)
      end
    end

    desc "Create an item."
    post :items do
      Item.new item_params
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [hashie-forbidden_attributes](https://github.com/Maxim-Filimonov/hashie-forbidden_attributes) gem as mentioned in the [grape documentation](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape):

> Additionally, if the version of your Rails is 4.0+ and the application uses the default model layer of ActiveRecord, you will want to use the hashie-forbidden_attributes gem. This gem disables the security feature of strong_params at the model layer, allowing you the use of Grape's own params validation instead.